# aggregate $push + $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I need to populate inside array...

```
messageModel.aggregate([
        {"$match": {$and: [
                    {$or: [{"to": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}, {"from": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)}]}
                ]
            }
        },

        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$conversationId",
                "conversation": {"$push": {'from': "$from"}}
            }

        },
        {"$lookup": {
                "from": "user",
                "localField": "conversation.from",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                "as": "to"
            }},
        {"$unwind": {"path": "$conversation.from"}},
        {"$project": {
                "conversation.from.firstName": "$conversation.from.firstName"
            }
        }
    ]
```

This return empty array what is wrong? it works when I don't use array, if just take $first element... Any solution?

Comment: try unwind before $lookup

Comment: same... I think it is some problem because array

Comment: where did you try `$first`? Also share your sample documents

Comment: Please do not post tags in the question title - [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)